# Есть функция Суммы двух соседних элементов?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция Суммы двух соседних элементов.

```js
var arr = [];
var newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  let j = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
  arr.push(j);
}
console.log("count array: " + arr.length);
console.log(arr);

function gcd(arr) {
  while (arr.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
      newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
    console.log(newArr);
    arr = newArr.slice();
    newArr = [];
  }
}

gcd(arr);

//gcd
function egcd(a, b) {
  if (a == 0)
    return b;

  while (b != 0) {
    if (a > b)
      a = a - b;
    else
      b = b - a;
  }

  return a;
}
```

Нужно переделать на gcd(x,y), где gcd обозначает наибольший общий делитель из двух соседних элементов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> newArr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
> ```

```
newArr[i] = egcd(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
```